# How to drag and scroll in grid for KendoReactJs

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, grid

Is there an alternative where react grid can scroll while having a row being dragged to the bottom part of the grid?

Comment: Any solution? I am stuck with same

Comment: sadly there is no solution with this one, we have contacted and filed a ticket with keno react and they does not support this api as of today.